# C++ Byte is implementation dependent

Tags: c++, byte, bit

I have been reading C Primer Plus.

It is said that:
Note that the meaning of byte is implementation dependent. So a 2-byte int could be 16 bits on one system and 32 bits on another.

Here I think I am not sure about this. From my understanding, 1 byte always = 8 bits, so it makes sense that `2-byte int = 2 * 8 = 16 bits`. But from this statement it sounds like some system define 1 byte = 16 bits. Is that correct? 
In general, how I should understand this statement?

Comment: A byte is at least 8 bits long. Virtually all modern systems use 8-bit bytes, but the standard technically allows bytes to be longer than 8 bits.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/bytes-review.html The FAQ-answer does not incorporate the restrictions alignment adds though. That's probably mentioned elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ standard, section 1.7 point 1 confirms this:

> The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte. ***A
>   byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic
>   execution character set (2.3) and the eight-bit code units*** of the
>   Unicode UTF-8 encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence
>   of bits, the number of which is ***implementation defined***. (...) 
>   The memory available to a C++ program consists of one or more
>   sequences of contiguous bytes. Every byte has a unique address.

Comment: Perhaps add: There are systems (especially digital signal processors (DSP) and micro-controllers) with bigger bytes.

Comment: True ! Also worth to mention : the term *octet* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_%28computing%29) allows to unambiguously refer to a unit of information of exactly 8 bits.

Answer (score 4):

Bytes are always composed of *at least* 8 bits. They can be larger than 8 bits, though this is fairly uncommon.

Answer (score 3):

One byte is not always 8-bits. Before octets (the term you want to use if you want to explicitly refer to an 8-bit byte), there were 4-, 6-, and 7-bit bytes. For the purposes of [modern] programming (in pretty much any language), you can assume it is at least 8 bits.

Comment: Is this still true for systems that a byte is not just 8 bits?

Comment: Technically, yes. "Byte" just means a group of bits. It only refers to 8 bits in the same way Kleenex refers to facial tissue :)

Comment: I remember that when I am on he bog

Answer (score 2):

Historically, a byte was not always 8 bits. Today it is, but long time ago, it could be 6, 7, 8, 9 ... so to have a language that could exploit the specifics of the hardware (for efficiency) but still letting the user express himself in a bit higher level language, they had to make sure the int type was mapped on the most natural fit for the hardware.